# Regain Sudo rights after removing from admin group

Tags: root, sudo

I accidentally removed myself from the admin group when editing the user. Now I can no longer use `sudo`. The error says: *ber is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be [reported](http://xkcd.com/838/).*

I booted up in rescue mode, but, when going into *root prompt*, it asks me for the root password. I don't have one, and providing with my own (first and only ubuntu-user) password, it won't allow entrance.

My harddisk is encrypted, but only the */home/user* part, not the entire disk, afaik.

What can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm well you've covered what I would have suggested first. Seems annoying that Rescue mode would hassle you for a password if the entire disk weren't encrypted (I don't know, that might be standard protocol).

I'd personally jump into a live environment (via Live CD or Live USB), mount the filesystem (assuming it *isn't* encrypted) and edit its `etc/group` file and add yourself back in. The resulting line should look something like this (though the GID may be different):

```
admin:x:115:oli
```

Or on Ubuntu 12.04, find the line for the `sudo` group instead of the `admin` group.

---

Alternatively, you can probably `chroot` from the LiveCD to run commands. (sudo password for the LiveCD is a blank password, just press return when prompted)

```
sudo mount /dev/sdYY /mnt  # change sdYY to your root partition
sudo mount --bind /dev  /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts  /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
```

```
sudo adduser your-username admin
```

For Ubuntu 12.04 and later, add the user to the `sudo` group instead of the `admin` group:

```
sudo adduser your-username sudo
```

`chroot` drops you off at a root shell inside your filesystem so should let you do fancy things like adding users to groups. It's most useful for fixing boot issues but it can do a lot of gubbins.

Comment: IMHO, you have to mount at least /dev and /proc to get a running bash in a chrooted environment, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @FUZxxl You're probably right, I've only ever done it to do fix a bootloader so that needed /dev mounting. I'll update it with a full compliment (mounting too much won't hurt)

Comment: There is no need to chroot the filesystem, you can modify `/etc/group` manually. If I'm not mistaken, a backup of the group file is also written to `/etc/group-`.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Yeah the that was the first suggestion I gave. Note the path won't be `/etc/group` because that would refer to the LiveCD's version. I gave `chroot` as an option because it's not wildly difficult and should still work.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, by `/etc/group`, I meant the `/etc/group` of the mounted partition, like `/mnt/etc/group`.

Comment: Here is what I did: dowload and burn an ubuntu ISO. Start with that CD as liveCD. From that session, mount the drive. `sudo gedit /media/10...e3/etc/group`. Added myself (*ber*) to *adm,dialout,cdrom,plugdev,lpadmin,admin* and *sambashare*

Comment: @Oli None of the `sudo mount --bind` commands are necessary. I've just tested on 15.04 to verify that a simple chroot, with no extra mounts except `/`, is (still) sufficient to add a user to a group, or change a password, from a live environment. [`/dev`, `/dev/pts`, `/proc`, and `/sys`, do *not* need to be mounted in the chroot for the `usermod`, `adduser`, and `passwd` commands to work.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10950646/) (`sudo` is also not necessary in the chroot--i.e., when running `adduser`--as one already has a root shell.)

Answer (score 7):

At the grub boot-up menu, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the kernel launch command-line and append the word `single` at its end. This should boot the system on single-user mode (as root) and allow you to perform any modifications.

Comment: This is good, quick and easy but does not always work.