# Is there any way to recover my sudo power?

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, ssh, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regain Sudo rights after removing from admin group](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29004/regain-sudo-rights-after-removing-from-admin-group)

I created a new user and changed the ssh config. I forgot to add root permission to the newly created user.

Now I need to undo my changes in ssh config. Is that possible without any sudo command?

Answer (score 0):

No. Can't you **log in as the admin user** (who was created at installation time)? If yes, log in and add the new user to the sudo group, where's the problem?

If no, do you have **physical access to the machine**? If yes, boot from a Ubuntu CD, mount your harddrive and add the user to the group manually. For example, assuming that `/dev/sdb1` is the partition on your hard drive that is mounted as root (`/`), then after booting the live CD, do:

```
sudo -i
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
cd /mnt/etc
nano group
```

(yeah, you can do that all from a GUI as well)

A simple text editor opens. Search for the line starting with "sudo". It may look something like this:

```
sudo:x:27:oldadmin
```

Assuming that `oldadmin` is the user name of the admin. If the new user's login name is `newuser`, modify that line to

```
sudo:x:27:oldadmin,newuser
```

save the file and reboot the computer. The `newuser` should have now the privilege to run sudo.

If you **do not have physical access to the machine**, you lost your administrative password and the root is not permitted to log in, then you have a problem, sir.