# how to get back sudo previledges?

Tags: sudo, 9.10, compaq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regain Sudo rights after removing from admin group](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29004/regain-sudo-rights-after-removing-from-admin-group)

I have been given a laptop with ubuntu 9.10 installed. it has only one User.
The problem is sudo is disabled and thus i cant use it to do anything. Reinstalling ubuntu is not an option as the institute im in current studying in has some net problems and i cannot download the newer OS (& i urgently need sudo). Also the person who has given me the laptop doesnt know anything about this. Please help.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29004/regain-sudo-rights-after-removing-from-admin-group