# Why am I suddenly not a sudoer anymore?

Tags: sudo, root

I booted up Ubuntu 12.10 today, and when trying to `sudo`, I entered my password as usual but it had said I'm not a sudoer. So I go and check my account under User Accounts, and for some reason Im now a standard user?

I tried re-adding myself to admin through recovery mode already, but it didn't work.

EDIT: UserMod command will not work. Get the error: usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.

EDIT 2: Thank you to all that helped! Your support is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Aditya There, the problem relates to entering recovery mode. *Here*, the problem is that changes made in recovery mode weren't effective. So this is not a duplicate of that. **fr057w1nd**: Administrator and sudoer effectively mean the same thing in Ubuntu, since the other mechanism whereby administrators may perform actions as root--PolicyKit--is based on the same details of group membership as being able to `sudo`-to-root.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Sortof new to Ubuntu.

Comment: @Aditya I don't think the'll help here, as this problem appears to be that the OP attempted to add to `admin`, when the proper group (in this version of Ubuntu) is `sudo`. Backward compat. makes `admin` work, but only *if it exists* (except on upgraded systems it doesn't). **fr057w1nd**: Not a problem. Hopefully [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/275929/22949) will enable you to fix this problem. BTW, if you're interested in the details of what makes a user an administrator in Ubuntu, you may want to read [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/245262) (but that's not necessary, for this issue).

Comment: Related: [Regain Sudo rights after removing from admin group](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29004/regain-sudo-rights-after-removing-from-admin-group)

Comment: @Aditya IMO highly detailed instructions for re-making oneself an administrator is an unnecessary duplication of effort, since [it's very similar to, and can be explained in relation to, resetting a password](http://askubuntu.com/a/84475/22949). (But *I do recommend keeping that link*; in light of new information, it may be more relevant than I thought, though this is only a duplicate of it if the part about `sudo` vs. `admin` groups is disregarded.)

Comment: Can anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Starting in Ubuntu 12.04, the `sudo` group confers administrative power to users. The `admin` group will too, but *only if it exists*, and unless you upgraded from a previous version or manually created it, it does not.

- For more information, see [What is the difference between the 'sudo' and 'admin' group?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43317/what-is-the-difference-between-the-sudo-and-admin-group)
- Even if you did upgrade starting from a version earlier than 12.04, if the event that caused this problem was the inadvertent *deletion* of the `admin` group, then an attempt to fix this by adding yourself to `admin` would also fail.

Therefore, you must add yourself to the `sudo` group rather than the `admin` group. To do this, boot in recovery mode and enter a root shell (as you did before), then run:

```
usermod -a -G sudo username
```

Make sure to replace **`username`** with your actual username.

Then, you'll be an administrator again.

(If that does not work or produces an error, please comment here to briefly explain what happened, and also edit your question to add as much information about what happened as possible.)

***Source:*** [How can I give admin permissions to my account?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84474/how-can-i-give-admin-permissions-to-my-account)

### When That Doesn't Work

You got the error `usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later`.

`usermod` is apparently not able to gain proper access to `/etc/passwd` (the file it must modify), even in recovery mode.

Hopefully, booting directly to a root shell *without* going through the recovery mode menu will work better. So try ["The Other Way Lucid"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword#The_Other_Way_Lucid) (but run `usermod -a -G sudo username` instead of `passwd username`, as before).

If that doesn't work, you can try [the solution by Oli that Aditya had suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/29006/22949), with two major caveats:

1. You can only use those instructions *if* you know enough about your system to "`change sdYY to your root partition`" as it demands (i.e., if you know the device name for your root partition).
2. Don't run `sudo adduser your-username admin` as it says; instead, run `adduser your-username sudo`. (Or `usermod -a -G your-username`.)

   The important thing is that you add yourself to `sudo` rather than `admin`.

   *(Feel free to skip this paragraph--it's about style and "best practices.")*
   But it's also unnecessary, and in my opinion somewhat poor form, to use `sudo` to run commands as root, when you're *already* in a root shell where all your commands run as root. I think this rapidly causes confusion about when one is and isn't in a root shell.

Or you can use [the instructions I wrote here](https://askubuntu.com/a/147023/22949), which explain how to obtain all the necessary information. They're long, but that is because they cover a variety of situations that probably don't apply for you, including not being able to log on to the machine at all, and wanting to reset the password as well as make a user an administrator. They also explain how to do everything without assuming much prior knowledge or experience (for example, they explain in detail how to boot from and access a useful desktop on a live CD).

**You have another option**: Those instructions of mine are really a general presentation the same technique that Oli wrote about more succinctly and more situation-specifically. So, *from what I wrote [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/147023/22949)*, here's how to find out what command to use *in place of* `sudo mount /dev/sdYY /mnt/boot # change sdYY to your root partition`:

> In your Ubuntu system (not the live CD/DVD/USB system), run this
>   command in the Terminal:
>
> ```
> mount | grep ' on / '
> ```
>
> You should include the spaces before `on` and after `/`.

> That command produces something like `/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)` as the output. The text before `on` (not including the space) is the device name of the partition that contains your Ubuntu system's root filesystem. Remember it (or write it down).

Then, once you've opened the Terminal on the live CD/DVD/USB:

> Run this command:
>
> ```
> sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
> ```
>
> Replace **`/dev/sda1`** with the device name of the partition
>   containing your Ubuntu system's root filesystem, if different.

Besides using the device name you found with the technique above, you should also use `/mnt` and *not* `/mnt/boot` as in [Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/29006/22949). But then you can continue on with [the instructions there](https://askubuntu.com/a/29006/22949).

Comment: Thanks, will try now. Will come back and say if it has worked or not.

Comment: Got an error. usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.

Comment: @fr057w1nd I've updated my answer with information that should help. I've given a couple of other ways to add yourself to the `sudo` group. The first and easiest way *might* work. If not, the other ways will almost certainly work.

Comment: Sorry for the huge delay, went out somewhere. But I found that none of them worked. I did, however, find a different method. Will put an answer up.

Answer (score 5):

**Recover your Sudo Privileges.**

1. At boot menu, go under Advanced options.
2. Select one with Recovery mode.
3. Go to "root"
4. Type and enter: mount -rw -o remount /
5. Type and enter: usermod -a -G sudo USERNAMEHERE
6. Type and enter: reboot
   You should have your Sudo Privileges back.

Comment: No, you had to mount first.

Comment: Gotcha. Cool, I'm glad you solved it!

Comment: Thanks! You helped alot too. Never thought of the usermod command!

Comment: Also, in case anything does happen again, I've created a backup admin account so I don't have to go through them troubles. Lol.