# user-name is not in sudoer file and su authentication failure

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, authentication, su

when using sudo command, I met the error: "uers-name is not in the sudoers file, and this incident will be reported". And then I tried some answers in the internet, such as "su root " and so on and then I got the error"su:authentication failure".
I knew there were many questions and answers about "not in the sudoers file" and "su:authentication failure" respectivley, but discussions are often like this:

1. as for "not in the sudoers file", the answer referred to "su root"
2. as for "su:authentication failure",the answer referred to"sudo"
   however, I met first "not in the sudoers file", and then follow instructions "su root" or "su -i",and I got error"authentication failure" , then some answers says to some"sudo" command to solve the "authentication failure". I couldn't use the "sudo" command, how could I use this to solve the "authentication failure" problem? Doesn't this mean a snake want to chase its tail?
   So far, I didn't see any answer that can explain explicitly about this problem and really have been stuck in it some time. Could anyone please give me clues on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I suddenly not a sudoer anymore?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275920/why-am-i-suddenly-not-a-sudoer-anymore)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Answer (score 1):

- When attempting to use `sudo`, an error `users-name is not in the sudoers file` indicates that your account is not authorized to use the `sudo` command to elevate to root privileges.
- When you attempt `su root`, or just `su`, it will not work on a default Ubuntu install. On Ubuntu, the root account is not enabled by default. That means you cannot log in to that account. Henceforth, you also cannot use  `su`  to switch to that account. A system administrator will instead use `sudo` to launch processes with `root` privileges on behalf of his own account, that has been granted permission to use sudo.

*Resolution*: ask your system administrator to [add your account to the `sudo`  group](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2214/how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-sudo-group).