# How to regain sudo permission when grub menu is unavailable?

Tags: grub2, permissions, sudo, groups

I inadvertently failed to append myself to a group by using `usermod -G group_name user_name` instead of `usermod -aG group_name user_name` and now belong only to the `group_name` group.

The problem is: I can not bring up the grub2 menu with <kbd>Left-Shift</kbd> on boot, therefore I can not drop to root login and reinstate my `sudo` membership.

Is there another way?

To be clear, I have not lost my password, I have inadvertently removed myself from the admin group.

Comment: You have to use a live flash drive. Oil's answer here describes how to do that - http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password (scroll down a bit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regain Sudo rights after removing from admin group](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29004/regain-sudo-rights-after-removing-from-admin-group)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen So, boot a stick, mount the system root and edit sudoers?  Or chroot into the system and usermod?

Comment: Yeah, both of us read that. Did *you* care to read what we suggested?

Comment: @muru beg your pardon, that should get me started!

Comment: Editing sudoers is not the best option. Chroot into the system and restore your group memberships with usermod - http://askubuntu.com/questions/79565/add-user-to-existing-group

Comment: Thanks bodhi.zazen.  I'll take that route.

Vis the mark down.  The combination of problems is particular.  It is not entirely obvious that each of the two suggestions here is relevant after trawling through many suggestions that offer no solution.  Should the question be deleted or left as a marker for others who find themselves unable to bring up the grub menu?

Comment: IMO, go ahead and answer your own question. I would upvote a quality answer

Answer (score -1):

Following the advice given here I did the following:

1. Boot from the installation stick (or disk)
2. In Unity bring up a terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.  If the boot sequence stalls for any reason (graphics in my case) switch to another tty.  I switched to tty2 with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
3. Mount your system root drive.  On my system this requires `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`
4. Gain access to the installed system by chrooting into it.  In my example I typed `sudo chroot /mnt`, because my system's root directory `/` is mounted there from the previous command.  You now have a bash session in your original installation with full privileges.
5. Enter `usermod -aG sudo user_name`
6. Reboot normally.
7. Rejoin all the default groups with

   ```
   sudo usermod -aG lpadmin,sambashare,adm,cdrom,dip,plugdev user_name
   ```

Comment: Just stop using `usermod` for adding groups. This whole mess could have been avoided if you'd run `adduser user_name group_name` in the first place.

Comment: So, @muru, the solution is to know everything about linux beforehand?  I'll try to be omniscient in future.

Comment: don't be stupid. Your problem was originally caused by **you** missing a crucial `usermod` option - `-a`. The solution is to be careful when you're messing with accounts. My comment was prompted by your continued usage of `usermod` when safer alternatives exist.

Comment: I simply followed a tutorial on how to set up kismet, made a slip of the keyboard and found myself in the situation described.  The tutorial did not offer alternatives.  Nor did it offer a tutorial in all aspects of using and administering a Linux system.  But thank you for the intelligence assessment.

Comment: You're most welcome.